Why am I seeing mixed font sizes being display emails from Apple Mail in Outlook?
I have an exchange account set up in Apple Mail. After sending a message to one or more recipients, the message displays unprofessionally. If the recipient also has Apple Mail, everything is OK. But if the recipient has Outlook, the font sizes are mixed up. Sometimes the entire paragraph changes and sometimes a single word.
The problem is irregular.
Apple Mail has manually set fonts (Arial 12) and sends as richText. Plain text is not an option because I have a graphic footer.
Below is a screenshot of what it looks like.
Screen

In order to further confirm if the issue is related to your Apple mail, please use Outlook to send the emails to check if there're any differences.

Is there any updates?

I was sent a ticket to Microsoft. They investigated the problem for over 2 weeks. They replied that it was Apple Mail's fault (what a surprise). The mail looks the same on Outlook for Windows and in the browser, so they ruled out Outlook's fault.
I opened the message as HTML code and found a few interesting anomalies in tags.
Examples:
should be font-family i see font-f=amily
should be Arial i see Ar=ial
should be ArialMT i see Ari=alMT
should be style=3D i see sty=e=3D
should be < div> i see <= div>
Screen
In general, the problem is not solved. The only solution I see at the moment is to switch to Outlook, but I am still looking for a solution.
